# TypeORM discards where clause

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm extending and improving an API built by another (unavailable) developer. It uses TypeORM, we use a PostgreSQL database.

This is the "function frame" (don't know the correct terminology) at the beginning of the file I intend to modify:

```
type Handler = RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, Query>;

const createNew = <TReq, TParent, TChild, TRes = DataNode.DataNode>(
    parentEntityClass: ObjectType<TParent>,
    childPropertyName: string,
    parentPropertyName: string,
    reqValidator: (body: TReq) => boolean,
    constraintSelector: (body: TReq) => string | number | Date | ObjectID,
    dataMapper: (body: TReq, res: Response) => Promise<TChild>,
    responseSerializer?: (
        entity: TChild,
        req?: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, Query>
    ) => Promise<TRes>
): Handler => asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const logger = req.getLogger();
    const db = req.getDbContext();

    const reqBody = RequestUtility.getJsonAndValidate<TReq>(
        req,
        reqValidator,
        logger
    );

    const child = await dataMapper(reqBody, res);

    if (parentEntityClass) {
        const parent = await QueryUtility.findOneOrFail(
            db,
            parentEntityClass,
            constraintSelector(reqBody)
        );

        const childsParentWrapped: { [k: string]: any } = {};

        logger.debug(`checking if child refs parent ${JSON.stringify({
            childProps: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child),
            prop: parentPropertyName
        })}`);

        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child).includes(parentPropertyName) ||
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child).includes(`__${parentPropertyName}__`)) {
            childsParentWrapped[parentPropertyName] = Promise.resolve(parent);

            Object.assign(child, childsParentWrapped);
        }

        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parent).includes(childPropertyName)) {
            await QueryUtility.addChild(db, parentEntityClass, childPropertyName, parent, child);
        } else {
            await db.manager.save(child);
        }
    } else {
        await db.manager.save(child);
    }

    const result = await responseSerializer(child, req);

    res.json(result);
});
```

This is the function (another part of the same file) I intend to modify.

```
type NewFile = { fileName: string};
type CreatedNewFileResponse = { uploadUrl: string; file: DataNode.DataNode };

export const createNewFile: Handler = createNew<NewFile, EUser, EFile, CreatedNewFileResponse>(
    EUser,
    "",
    "user",
    (body) => body.fileName ? true : false,
    (body) => null,
    async (body, res) => {
        const newFile = new EFile();
        const fileType = body.fileName.toLowerCase().split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
        if (['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'png'].includes(fileType[1])){
            newFile.fileName = body.fileName;
            newFile.fileType = 'image';
            newFile.storageProvider = "internal-storage";
            newFile.isMarkedForDeletion = false;
            const id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.locals.jwtPayload.id));
            newFile.user = Promise.resolve(
                        await getRepository(EUser).findOne({where: { id } })    
                        );
            return newFile;

        } else if (['avi', 'wmv', 'mp4', 'mkv', 'flv', 'mov'].includes(fileType[1])) {
            newFile.fileName = body.fileName;
            newFile.fileType = 'video';
            newFile.storageProvider = "internal-storage";
            newFile.isMarkedForDeletion = false;
            const id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.locals.jwtPayload.id));
            newFile.user = Promise.resolve(
                        await getRepository(EUser).findOne({where: { id } })    
                        );

            return newFile;

        } else if (['ogg', 'wma', 'wave', 'mp3', 'wav', 'm4a'].includes(fileType[1])) {
            newFile.fileName = body.fileName;
            newFile.fileType = 'audio';
            newFile.storageProvider = "internal-storage";
            newFile.isMarkedForDeletion = false;
            const id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.locals.jwtPayload.id));
            newFile.user = Promise.resolve(
                        await getRepository(EUser).findOne({where: { id } })    
                        );

            return newFile;

        } else {
            throw errors.create(BadRequestError);
        }
    },
    async (newFile, req) => {
        const minioContext = req.getMinioContext();
        let uploadUrl = await minioContext.client.presignedUrl(
            "PUT",
            minioContext.bucket,
            newFile.fileName,
            7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            { query: {}, headers: { host: req.hostname } }
        );
        uploadUrl = uploadUrl.replace(
            `${minioContext.config.host}:${minioContext.config.port}`,
            req.hostname
        ).replace("localhost", `${minioContext.config.minioUrl}`).replace("http", "https")

        return {
            uploadUrl,
            file: await DataNode.fromFile(newFile)
        };
    }
);
```

The function works (as in, it serves it's purpose without errors) and inserts the intended row on the database. But on the line that states `newFile.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.locals.jwtPayload.id));`, although it does retrieve the correct information (it returns the id from the JWT), that information gets discarded as we can see on the PostgreSQL log, utilizing then the first row from the Users table (which means, not using the id we retrieved):

```
2020-12-04 18:39:20.395 UTC [690] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '1'
2020-12-04 18:39:20.405 UTC [690] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT "User"."id" AS "User_id", "User"."created" AS "User_created", "User"."updatedAt" AS "User_updatedAt", "User"."username" AS "User_username", "User"."password" AS "User_password", "User"."role" AS "User_role", "User"."firstName" AS "User_firstName", "User"."lastName" AS "User_lastName", "User"."email" AS "User_email" FROM "Users" "User" WHERE "User"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
2020-12-04 18:39:20.405 UTC [690] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '1'
2020-12-04 18:39:20.413 UTC [690] LOG:  statement: SELECT "User"."id" AS "User_id", "User"."created" AS "User_created", "User"."updatedAt" AS "User_updatedAt", "User"."username" AS "User_username", "User"."password" AS "User_password", "User"."role" AS "User_role", "User"."firstName" AS "User_firstName", "User"."lastName" AS "User_lastName", "User"."email" AS "User_email" FROM "Users" "User" LIMIT 1
2020-12-04 18:39:20.420 UTC [690] LOG:  statement: START TRANSACTION
2020-12-04 18:39:20.429 UTC [690] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO "Files"("fileName", "fileType", "storageProvider", "isMarkedForDeletion", "userId") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id", "created", "updatedAt"
2020-12-04 18:39:20.429 UTC [690] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'test.jpg', $2 = 'image', $3 = 'internal-storage', $4 = 'f', $5 = '2'
2020-12-04 18:39:20.433 UTC [690] LOG:  statement: COMMIT
```

As you can see on line 2 of the log snipet, the where clause is respected. But when we reach the part where the information is to be inserted into the database (line 4 of the snipet), the where clause is discarded.

I don't know enought to debug this alone.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I ended up changing "user" to "".

Somehow that solved the problem and now the query that reaches my postgres includes the userId as I wanted.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be specifying only the column in the where clause and not the value. Assuming the value of id is in a variable called 'id' the find statement should be like:
await getRepository(EUser).findOne({where: { id: id } })